# CreateFile and memory management

Tags: c++, memory-management, createfile

I am creating/opening a file using CreateFile() Windows API.  Let's assume that my drive has a bad sector and the file could not be open or an attempt to write to this file failed.
If I will recreate the file using the same CreateFile() API, will it be created in the same memory location on drive as the previous one (and so the bad sector will be there again) or a different piece of memory will be picked by OS and I have a chance to avoid the bad sector?

I guess my question is what is the way Windows allocates a memory on physical drive when the file is created by CreateFile() function?

Comment: The new API call will generate a new handle. This API is not low level enough to specify access and placement on the physical drive. Windows will always determine that which is why it shouldn't write to a bad sector in the first place. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: In my software I am trying to take care of cases when something goes wrong with writing to file. This may be a case of physical drive failure or just a bad sector. In case of bad sector I want to try and recreate the file and write to it again. The question is - is there a chance that I will not hit the same bad sector again in the new created file?

Comment: People normally solve this problem by using a good filesystem. NTFS automatically detects & flags bad sectors. It also tries to recover the data and stores it in another (good) sector. In case of FAT, a `chkdsk /r` will mark sectors as bad and Windows will automatically avoid them. Any special reason to be worried about data corruption? I'd suggest using RAID, or replicate over network, or in a last resort, locally write the data twice, and rely on checksums.

Comment: Keep in mind that different Windows/File System versions may behave differently. And there are no any guarantees what future Windows will do in such case.

Comment: If you really want to learn how Windows manages the hard drive, you need to read Windows Internals: http://amzn.com/0735648735

Answer (score 1):

CreateFile returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` if it fails.

According to the MSDN, call `GetLastError` to find out why.